# Sort the output of the "who" command

Tags: linux, shell, sort

I'm trying to sort the output of the who command but I guess I'm kinda lost on this one.

I want to sort it based on who just logged in.

Thanks

Comment: Can you give us some sample output and explain which fields you want to sort on exactly? (Does `who | sort -k3` do what you want?)

Answer (score 3):

Do you try using sort command:

```
who | sort -r -k3
```